# Redesign Init (MKAnnotation)

Tags: swift, firebase, mkannotation

```
class Point: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
var id: String?
var title: String?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var subtitle: String?



init(id: String, dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){
    self.id = id

    if let title = dictionary["title"] as? String {
        self.title = title
    }

    if let subtitle = dictionary["subtitle"] as? String {
        self.subtitle = subtitle
    }

    if let coords = dictionary["coordinates"] as? [String:[String:Double]] {
        self.coordinate.latitude = coords.values.first!["latitude"]!
        self.coordinate.longitude = coords.values.first!["longitude"]!
    }
   super.init()
}
/*
init(title: String, subtitle: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
    self.coordinate = coordinate

}*/
```

}

I implemented initializer for creating Point on Map. I must redesign init because I use Firebase and results from database are in dictionary.
It writes: Property self.coordinate not initialized at implicitly generated super.init call

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> init(id: String, dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){
>     self.id = id
>
>     if let title = dictionary["title"] as? String {
>         self.title = title
>     }
>
>     if let subtitle = dictionary["subtitle"] as? String {
>         self.subtitle = subtitle
>     }
>
>     if let coords = dictionary["coordinates"] as? [String:[String:Double]] {
>         self.coordinate.latitude = coords.values.first!["latitude"]!
>         self.coordinate.longitude = coords.values.first!["longitude"]!
>     }
>     super.init()
> }
> ```

So, the problem here mostly lies in the fact that you only ever initialize your `coordinate` property within an `if`.  Because `coordinate` is not marked as an optional, it much be given a value before you call `super.init()`, as per the rules of Swift initializers.

And because you initialize it within an `if` only, there's a chance that the `if` fails and you never initialize it at all.  This would leave the instance in a completely invalid state, which is not allowed per the rules of Swift initializers and fails [the first safety check](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html).

> **Safety check 1**
>
> A designated initializer must ensure that all of the properties
>   introduced by its class are initialized before it delegates up to a
>   superclass initializer.

You *could* make `coordinate` an optional instance variable, must like your other instance variables.  However, I'd argue that probably makes most sense is that `id` & `title` are probably also non-optional, and all of these properties probably should be `let` constants.

As such, I'd rewrite your class and that initializer as such:

```
class Point: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    let id: String
    let title: String?
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let subtitle: String?

    init?(id: String, dictionary: [String: AnyObject]){
        self.id = id

        title = dictionary["title"] as? String

        subtitle = dictionary["subtitle"] as? String

        guard let 
            coordinates = dictionary["coordinates"] as? [String: [String: Double]], 
            latitude = coordinates.values.first?["latitude"],
            longitude = coordinates.values.first?["longitude"] else {

                return nil
        }

        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

       super.init()
    }
}
```

Now you have a *failable initializer*.  If any of the values in the dictionary is not correct, the initializer returns `nil`.  Otherwise, your values are all properly initialized.

Comment: Title has to optional according MKAnnotation protocol & coordinate can't be optional.

Comment: That's not even close to what your question says.

Comment: Error: All stored properties of a class instance must be initialized before returning nil from an initializer.

Comment: Any idea please? I need to create object from this dictionary.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?  Sounds like an old version if you're getting that error.